# Installing Jenkins Plugins to Docker Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile with `jenkins` as the base image:

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
ENV JENKINS_MIRROR http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org
RUN for plugin in git-client git ws-cleanup ; do wget -O $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/${plugin}.hpi $JENKINS_MIRROR/plugins/${plugin}/latest/${plugin}.hpi ; done
EXPOSE 8080
```

I'm trying to install some additional plugins but it gives me an error saying `no such file or directory`
[image]

I then started and connected to the container of this build step in order to "debug" the error:
[image]

However, I could not find out the cause because every directory seems to exist. Furthermore, if I then run the for-loop manually in the bash, all plugins are installed correctly...

I further noticed, that the installation of the the plugins works, if I install them in the root directory as follows:

```
RUN for plugin in git-client git ws-cleanup ; do wget -O ${plugin}.hpi $JENKINS_MIRROR/plugins/${plugin}/latest/${plugin}.hpi ; done
```

However, this is the wrong place as they have to be placed in the directory $JENKINS_HOME/plugins

Why I am not able to install the plugins in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I can't read your screenshots, but you don't seem to be following the official instructions. See https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-ci.org-docker under "Installing more tools". Note:

- You should save the plugins to `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins`
- You could use a `plugins.txt` file instead, which contains the names of your plug-ins, and you can process with the provided `plugins.sh` script. This looks like:

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

I think the reason your approach wasn't working was to do with some processing in the start-up script.

Comment: Adrian, I did exactly what you wrote, but still same problem like Rene has

Comment: @vogash did you edit a running container or a dockerfile? Adrian, the script is now called install-plugins.sh as plugin.sh returns an err.

Comment: install-plugins.sh doesn't accept a txt file. It does however accept input from stdin.


`RUN cat /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt | /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh`

Comment: RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

Comment: thanks @JasonRitchie & 3h4x, I've updated the answer.

Comment: does anyone have an example of what plugins.txt might look like? maybe some bitbucket plugins?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Perhaps this can help you https://github.com/jenkinsci/incrementals-tools#updating-versions-for-jenkins-docker-images

Comment: For what solved it was using jenkins/jenkins:lts and not jenkins/jenkins see https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 15):

`install-plugins.sh` is deprecated. I had to switch to `jenkins-plugin-cli`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

...

RUN jenkins-plugin-cli \
    --plugins \
    git \
    workflow-aggregator \
    blueocean \
    other-plugins
```

`jenkins-plugin-cli` also supports `-f` parameter, which gets the list of plugins as a file.

See [Jenkins Official Documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#usage-1) for details.