# Configuring Jenkins plugin installed via Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

I have a Dockerfile to create a Jenkins image where I install the `locale:1.4` plugin via the [method described elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328489/1725871).

The issue is that Jenkins has a tendency to display the UI using the locale set in the browser `da_DK`

I use the Locale plugin to set it to `en_GB` and set the **Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users** (It is easier to search for things on SO, etc when the terms are in english)

My question is how do I set the configuration in the dockerfile?

**My Dockerfile**

```
# https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

#set executors
COPY executors.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy

#add plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

# drop back to the regular jenkins user - good practice
USER jenkins
EXPOSE 8095
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging around `$JENKINS_HOME` on another jenkins installation, I found `locale.xml`

adding the following lines to `Dockerfile` after the plugin installation solved it:

```
# add locale config
COPY locale.xml /var/jenkins_home/locale.xml
```