# jenkins failed to install plugins - docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Below is the relevant snippet from jenkins image(2.190.2 version) for installation of plugins:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.190.2
#......
# ...... 
# Add jenkins plugin
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

---

where below `plugins.txt` list was prepared at the time of jenkins 1.642.1 version:

```
git:latest
git-client:latest
git-server:latest
github:latest
github-api:latest
github-branch-source:latest
docker-commons:latest
docker-workflow:latest
docker-build-publish:latest
dockerhub-notification:latest
aws-credentials:latest
aws-java-sdk:latest
amazon-ecs:latest
workflow-aggregator:latest
workflow-api:latest
workflow-basic-steps:latest
workflow-cps-global-lib:latest
workflow-cps:latest
workflow-durable-task-step:latest
workflow-job:latest
workflow-scm-step:latest
workflow-step-api:latest
workflow-support:latest
workflow-multibranch:latest
pipeline-stage-step:latest
pipeline-stage-view:latest
pipeline-input-step:latest
pipeline-build-step:latest
pipeline-rest-api:latest
icon-shim:latest
async-http-client:latest
structs:latest
credentials:latest
plain-credentials:latest
ssh-credentials:latest
credentials-binding:latest
authentication-tokens:latest
momentjs:latest
handlebars:latest
scm-api:latest
mapdb-api:latest
subversion:latest
durable-task:latest
script-security:latest
mailer:latest
ace-editor:latest
jquery-detached:latest
cloudbees-folder:latest
branch-api:latest
zentimestamp:latest
token-macro:latest
jackson2-api:latest
```

---

below is the error in `docker-compose logs`:

```
Attaching to docker-jenkins_jenkins_1
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m webroot: 
.....
.......
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: SSH Credentials Plugin version 1.18 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Trilead API Plugin version 1.0.4 is older than required. To fix, install version 1.0.5 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:33.848+0000 [id=32]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Credentials Binding Plugin v1.20 (credentials-binding)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Credentials Binding Plugin version 1.20 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - SSH Credentials Plugin version 1.18 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:33.920+0000 [id=32]    INFO    j.b.a.SecurityProviderInitializer#addSecurityProvider: Initializing Bouncy Castle security provider.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.255+0000 [id=32]    INFO    j.b.a.SecurityProviderInitializer#addSecurityProvider: Bouncy Castle security provider initialized.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.256+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Docker Commons Plugin v1.15 (docker-commons)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Docker Commons Plugin version 1.15 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Credentials Binding Plugin version 1.20 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.261+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: REST API Plugin v2.12 (pipeline-rest-api)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Pipeline: REST API Plugin version 2.12 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - pipeline-graph-analysis version 1.4 is missing. To fix, install version 1.4 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.262+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Stage View Plugin v2.12 (pipeline-stage-view)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Pipeline: Stage View Plugin version 2.12 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Pipeline: REST API Plugin version 2.12 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.263+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Mailer Plugin v1.29 (mailer)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Jenkins Mailer Plugin version 1.29 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - display-url-api version 2.3.1 is missing. To fix, install version 2.3.1 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.264+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.18 (workflow-basic-steps)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Pipeline: Basic Steps version 2.18 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api version 4.5.5-3.0 is missing. To fix, install version 4.5.5-3.0 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Jenkins Mailer Plugin version 1.29 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.266+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Git client plugin v3.0.0 (git-client)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Jenkins Git client plugin version 3.0.0 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api version 4.5.10-1.0 is missing. To fix, install version 4.5.10-1.0 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - SSH Credentials Plugin version 1.18 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - jsch version 0.1.55.1 is missing. To fix, install version 0.1.55.1 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.267+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins GIT server Plugin v1.8 (git-server)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Jenkins GIT server Plugin version 1.8 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Jenkins Git client plugin version 3.0.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.268+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries v2.15 (workflow-cps-global-lib)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries version 2.15 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Jenkins GIT server Plugin version 1.8 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.270+0000 [id=26]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline v2.6 (workflow-aggregator)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Pipeline version 2.6 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Pipeline: Stage View Plugin version 2.12 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - lockable-resources version 2.3 is missing. To fix, install version 2.3 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.272+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Git plugin v4.0.0 (git)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Jenkins Git plugin version 4.0.0 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Jenkins Git client plugin version 3.0.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.273+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin GitHub plugin v1.29.5 (github)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: GitHub plugin version 1.29.5 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - display-url-api version 2.0 is missing. To fix, install version 2.0 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Jenkins Git plugin version 4.0.0 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.275+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Subversion Plug-in v2.12.2 (subversion)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Jenkins Subversion Plug-in version 2.12.2 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - SSH Credentials Plugin version 1.18 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.281+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin CloudBees Docker Hub/Registry Notification v2.4.0 (dockerhub-notification)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: CloudBees Docker Hub/Registry Notification version 2.4.0 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Docker Commons Plugin version 1.15 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.282+0000 [id=33]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Amazon Web Services SDK v1.11.670 (aws-java-sdk)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Amazon Web Services SDK version 1.11.670 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api version 4.5.10-2.0 is missing. To fix, install version 4.5.10-2.0 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.283+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin CloudBees AWS Credentials Plugin v1.28 (aws-credentials)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: CloudBees AWS Credentials Plugin version 1.28 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Amazon Web Services SDK version 1.11.670 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.284+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin v1.3.2 (docker-build-publish)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin version 1.3.2 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Docker Commons Plugin version 1.15 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.285+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Docker Pipeline v1.21 (docker-workflow)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Docker Pipeline version 1.21 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - Pipeline: Basic Steps version 2.18 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     

[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.286+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin v1.23 (amazon-ecs)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin version 1.23 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api version 4.5.5-3.0 is missing. To fix, install version 4.5.5-3.0 or later.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - CloudBees AWS Credentials Plugin version 1.28 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m 2019-11-11 17:40:34.287+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin GitHub Branch Source Plugin v2.5.8 (github-branch-source)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m java.io.IOException: GitHub Branch Source Plugin version 2.5.8 failed to load.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m  - GitHub plugin version 1.29.5 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:922)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:545)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1118)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
[36mjenkins_1  |[0m     at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
```

---

After connecting to jenkins at `localhost:8080` for the first time, I just used initial password and did not configure anything else and logged in as admin.

---

Above plugin list need change in missing dependencies for 2.190.2 version of jenkins.

How to resolve these plugin dependency issues? for jenkins 2.190.2 version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328489/3317808

Comment: Not sure what guidance your comment is providing; juat edit your question w/details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems going on. As you said, you are using jenkins:2.190.2 but your plugins list is from: jenkins:1.647 (2016/02/04). A lot has changed, not just in the major bump, but in each LTS as well and in the plugins.

[`docker/plugins.sh`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/plugins.sh) has been superseded by [`docker/install-plugins.sh`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh). Usage [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#preinstalling-plugins).

> [echo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/7d1ab73338e76b49c856e07a63550d80eeb35bf3/plugins.sh#L15) "WARN: plugins.sh is deprecated, please switch to install-plugins.sh"

`install-plugins.sh` will resolve and download all dependencies for your [plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) (each plugin list lists them in the details on the site), so your managed list can be much shorter. Just list the top-level plugins you need and it will resolve all dependencies. Maven plugins have progressively dropped unused dependencies as well.

*NB: if you want a known configuration (not latest), run once with the master list using latest, then check-in that and the resolved list. Feed the resolved list to docker instance.*

You can use this script to simplify your list:

```
println "Jenkins Instance : " + Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer('').getHostName() + " - " + Jenkins.getInstance().getRootUrl() 
println "Installed Plugins: "
println "=================="
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.sort(false) { a, b -> a.getShortName().toLowerCase() <=> b.getShortName().toLowerCase()}.each { plugin ->
   println "${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()} | ${plugin.getDisplayName()} "
}

println""
println "Plugins Dependency tree (...: dependencies; +++: dependants) :"
println "======================="
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.sort(false) { a, b -> a.getShortName().toLowerCase() <=> b.getShortName().toLowerCase()}.each { plugin ->
   println "${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()} | ${plugin.getDisplayName()} "
   println "+++ ${plugin.getDependants()}"
   println "... ${plugin.getDependencies()}"
   println ''
}
```

Or you could start w/:

```
credentials-binding
workflow-aggregator
docker-plugin
amazon-ecs
```

where, for example, workflow-aggregator:2.6 (Pipeline) pulls in:

```
... [lockable-resources (2.3), pipeline-stage-view (2.10), workflow-api (2.29), workflow-basic-steps (2.11), workflow-cps-global-lib (2.11), workflow-cps (2.56), workflow-durable-task-step (2.22), workflow-job (2.25), workflow-multibranch (2.20), workflow-scm-step (2.6), workflow-step-api (2.16), workflow-support (2.20), cloudbees-folder (6.6), credentials (2.1.18), git-client (2.7.3), jackson2-api (2.8.11.3), pipeline-build-step (2.7), pipeline-input-step (2.8), pipeline-milestone-step (1.3.1), pipeline-stage-step (2.3), scm-api (2.2.8), structs (1.15), pipeline-model-definition (1.3.2)]
```

and work until your list is covered. You may wish to drop or replace some ( eg: zentimestamp).

I answer similar plugin upgrade issues in a [DevOps answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9749/13379). Aside from the list of dependencies can change for every plugin release (hence the auto-dependency resolution == good), Jenkins has progressively been unbundling plugins. They provide a [split-plugins.txt](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/split-plugins.txt) list for reference (also read [split-plugin-cycles.txt](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/split-plugin-cycles.txt)). tri-lead is the latest on the list. Seems one of your plugins depends on the previously bundled version (so you have a copy of 1.0.4), but it's not on your explicit `plugins.txt` and `plugins.sh` won't pull dependencies.

*NB: You may find you may temporarily have to explicitly include unbundled plugins until a newer release of your plugin explicitly declares the dependency.*

There's also the issue of plugins/release compatibility, probably not applicable in your case. Plugins all depend on a base Jenkins version, so if running an old Jenkins version, newer versions will not be loadable. The reverse may also be true: non-updated plugins may break on a newer Jenkins. The [Update Centre](https://updates.jenkins.io/) (and [documentation](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/update-center2/tree/master/site) ) explains that.

Finally, you should be reviewing the [Upgrade Guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/) and [LTS Changelog](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/) as you move up Jenkins versions. [Same for plugins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/). There is a major initiative to [move plugin documentations and changelogs into the repos](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/10/21/plugin-docs-on-github/). Just relying on `latest` and expecting everything to work is something of a leap of faith.

Comment: Got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821303/apt-get-error-version-519-03-43-0ubuntu-bionic-for-docker-ce-was-not-fou

Comment: Did I miss any pllugin that is AWS ECS related in `plugins.txt`?https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

Comment: I do not use aws and don't know your specific setup or needs. My advice is look at [plugins.jenkins.io/](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) for aws or amazon plugins and their dependencies, compare your original liat, tje new derivediat and figure it out. You have all the tools now.