# apt-get error: Version '5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic' for 'docker-ce' was not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get, docker-ce

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) 
provides syntax to install specific version of `docker-ce`:

`$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION_STRING> docker-ce-cli=<VERSION_STRING> containerd.io`

---

On similar line, below `dockerfile` uses the above syntax:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

USER root

ARG DOCKER_GID=497

# Create Docker Group with GID
# Set default value of 497 if DOCKER_GID set to blank string by Docker compose
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker

# Install base packages for docker, docker-compose & ansible
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 && \
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get -y install bc \
                    gawk \
                    libffi-dev \
                    musl-dev \
                    apt-transport-https \
                    curl \
                    python3 \
                    python3-dev \
                    python3-setuptools \
                    gcc \
                    make \
                    libssl-dev \
                    python3-pip 

# Used at build time but not runtime
ARG DOCKER_VERSION=5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic

# Install the latest Docker CE binaries and add user `jenkins` to the docker group
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
      "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
      $(lsb_release -cs) \
      stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
        docker-ce-cli=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
        containerd.io && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins

ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE=1.24.1

# Install docker compose
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE:-1.24.1}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \
    -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN pip3 install ansible boto3

# Change to jenkins user
USER jenkins

# Add jenkins plugin
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

---

fails at line below(on build):

```
apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
            docker-ce-cli=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
            containerd.io && \
```

where default values are retrieved from command: `apt-cache madison docker-ce | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'` in my local docker host

---

where `docker-compose build` gives below error:

```
Reading state information...
E: Version '5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic' for 'docker-ce' was not found
E: Version '5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic' for 'docker-ce-cli' was not found
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     curl     gnupg-agent     software-properties-common &&     curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey &&     add-apt-repository       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")       $(lsb_release -cs)       stable" &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic}         docker-ce-cli=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic}         containerd.io &&     usermod -aG docker jenkins' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

---

`apt-get -y install docker-ce  docker-ce-cli  containerd.io` is able to download and install the latest version of `ubuntu` packages, but why download and install of specific version of `ubuntu` package fails?

```
apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
                docker-ce-cli=${DOCKER_VERSION:-5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic} \
                containerd.io && \
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've selected Docker versions based on what's available on your build host, not what's available inside the container image you're building. The jenkins:lts image is based on Debian Stretch, not Ubuntu Bionic.

Dockerfiles are actually just running fairly ordinary Docker operations. So, for example, you can run `docker run -ti -u root jenkins/jenkins:lts /bin/bash`, run your RUN scripts by hand, and check the `apt-cache` output inside the container:

```
# apt-cache madison docker-ce
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.4~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.3~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.2~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.1~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.0~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
```

Also, a failed docker build should leave the partially-complete image around; so you can use that directly to investigate a failure. As an example with a trivially failing step `RUN false`:

```
⋮
Removing intermediate container baaeab34bb8c
 ---> 6d34bab07796
Step 3/3 : RUN false
 ---> Running in 8347f442dfaa
The command '/bin/sh -c false' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The `6d34bab07796` image is left around. You can pass that to `docker run` and investigate why the command failed. The `8347f442dfaa` container is also left around, though exited; you can use the various `docker container` subcommands to investigate it as well.

Comment: `docker run -ti -u root 8347f442dfaa /bin/bash`.-ti gets you an interactive terminal session, -u root overrides the image's default user.