# Jenkins plugins for old versions

Tags: jenkins

Fore some reasons I have to use Jenkins 2.32 and I need to install some plugins there. Machine with it has no internet, so I only can upload plugin file to install it from file.

So, the problem is there any easy way to obtain required plugin for required Jenkins version with all it's dependencies?

p.s.

I can't update Jenkins - it's out of my power.

p.p.s.

I find only way to download old versions of plugin, but by this way I can't check dependencies and required jenkins version before loading.

Comment: Did the information provided help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had such an environment before.

Warning: it's an annoying process.

Because there was no internet, we uploaded all plugins manually, i.e. looking at the plugin page (e.g. https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) and then downloading from the archive (e.g. https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/git) the `.hpi` file. As you have to use a relatively old version of Jenkins you may want to check the changelog of the plugin, if you have to use an older version.

In addition on each plugin page the dependencies are listed and you have to repeat the above steps for each dependency.

The only good thing is that usually Jenkins gives you hints, which dependencies are missing after you uploaded a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably extract the information out of the [plugin-versions.json](https://updates.jenkins.io/current/plugin-versions.json) in the [Jenkins Update Center](https://updates.jenkins.io/).

For more information about the layout of update center, see [this document](https://github.com/jenkinsci/backend-update-center2/blob/master/site/LAYOUT.md).

You may also find my previous response on [jenkins failed to install plugins - docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815327/598141) (with groovy scripts) helpful