# How to have any version of Jenkins with Git plugin <= 4.11.3

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to install jenkins Git plugin version 4.11.3 or older version installed on Linux (https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/releases/)

But, when adding git.hpi 4.11.3 version manually I get lots of dependencies mismatch problems... and when trying to install each dependency it fails because it needs other mismatched dependency (cycle of dependency mismatch..). I even tried on older version of jenkins by changing WAR files too to no avail.

Comment: Installing older plugins including their dependencies is already in existing Q&A _[Jenkins plugins for old versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317736/jenkins-plugins-for-old-versions)_