# How to create directory in docker image?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins, devops

I tried `mkdir -p` it didn't work.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.363-jdk11

ENV PLUGIN_DIR /var/jenkins_home/plugins

RUN echo $PLUGIN_DIR

RUN mkdir -p $PLUGIN_DIR

RUN ls $PLUGIN_DIR

# WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home/plugins # Can't use this, as it changes the permission to root
# which breaks the plugin installation step
# # COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
# # RUN jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt --verbose
#
#
# # disable the setup wizard as we will set up jenkins as code 
# ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
#
# ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /configs/jcasc.yaml
```

The build fails!

```
docker build -t jenkins:test.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   51.2kB
Step 1/5 : FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.363-jdk11
 ---> 90ff7cc5bfd1
Step 2/5 : ENV PLUGIN_DIR /var/jenkins_home/plugins
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a158958aab0
Step 3/5 : RUN echo $PLUGIN_DIR
 ---> Running in ce56ef9146fc
/var/jenkins_home/plugins
Step 4/5 : RUN mkdir -p $PLUGIN_DIR
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dbc4e12b9808
Step 5/5 : RUN ls $PLUGIN_DIR
 ---> Running in 9a0edb027862
```

I need this because Jenkins deprecated old plugin installation method. The new cli installs plugins to `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins` instead.

Also:

```
+$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash --name jenkins jenkins:test.1
jenkins@7ad71925f638:/$ ls /var/jenkins_home/
jenkins@7ad71925f638:/$
```

Comment: why do you think that mkdir didn't work? `RUN` command runs during when you building the image, that's why the `ls` doesn't show any result. Try to define a `CMD` command that will actually execute `ls` on the folder you were trying to create. The chances are that you'll see that folder and the container will exit - but its a good tool to debug. Then you can use other commands to see what went wrong (maybe permissions on folder are lacking and jenkind doesn't see the plugins, who knows) - it will be beyond the scope of the current question though

Comment: I tried running the image afterwards. Exec into it. The directory is not there.

Comment: Ah, you take from the env, and its defined wrong. use `=` instead in ENV definition: `ENV PLUGIN_DIR=/var/jenkins_home/plugins` - I see that someone has already answered that. Alternatively try 'hardcoded' path to mkdir just to make sure it works,...

Comment: That's not the issue. Tried it. 
Also as you can see in the build output for `echo` it correctly outputs the value.
I had tried with hardcoded path before. Same problem.

Comment: Does [Installing Jenkins Plugins to Docker Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328278/installing-jenkins-plugins-to-docker-jenkins) describe your actual problem?  It looks like there's standard support in the image for installing plugins.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yup. I tried that before going with this path. They have deprecated `install-plugins.sh`. It used to work perfectly with that script. I'm trying to upgrade Jenkins as well as plugins. The new plugin cli works differently and installs the plugin to another location. But  Jenkins doesn't recognize it and gives me a bunch of errors. I thought I will do this as a work around. That's when this bizarre thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The official Jenkins image on dockerhub declare VOLUME /var/jenkins_home, and subsequent changes to that directory (even in derived images) are discarded.**

To workaround, you can execute mkdir as ENTRYPOINT.
And to verify that its working you can add an sleep to enter into the container and verify. It work !.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.363-jdk11

ENV PLUGIN_DIR /var/jenkins_home/plugins

RUN echo $PLUGIN_DIR

USER root 

RUN echo "#!/bin/sh \n mkdir -pv $PLUGIN_DIR && sleep inf" > ./mkdir.sh

RUN chmod a+x ./mkdir.sh

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "./mkdir.sh"]
```

after

- `docker build . -t <image_name>`
- `docker run -d <image_name> --name <container_name>`
- `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`

and you will see your directory

Sources:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/simple-mkdir-p-not-working/42179
- https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins

Comment: Yup. This was the issue. Didn't know about the `VOLUME` directive and it's behavior. Thank you :)